# listview move up item position

Tags: java, android, file, listview

I'm trying to move the item's position on `ListView` by pressing a button which will move up one row of the list.I tried looking for other answers on SO but their `ListView` was populated from an `ArrayList` whilst mine from `fileList()`

Do I need to somehow sort the files in `fileList()`? or is using `ArrayList` enough for me to change their positions?

I used `ArrayList` to get the item's position

How I populate my `ListView`

```
String[] SavedFiles;
String dataDr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address);

    dataDr = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    showDirFile(dataDr);
}

void showDirFile(String dirpth)
{
    String path = dirpth+"/files";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);

    SavedFiles = new String[file.length];
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());

        SavedFiles[i] = file[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            SavedFiles);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

How I get the item's position

```
OnItemClickListener getFileEditContent = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get item's file name according to position
        String clickedFile = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        stringArrayList.add(clickedFile)

        //  Get item position
        intArrayList.add(position);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used `String[] SavedFiles;` for showing list using adapter.

On click of an Item you want to move it up for that write logic for swapping array items and notify adapter.

Your logic will make the top item to current one and current one to top one.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself by using the `Collections.swap` method

Example

```
Collections collections;

void positionChange(){

    //to store arrays into ArrayList
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myDataFiles));

    //to get the item's position @ get the first item in array if multiple arrays exist
    String currentPos = String.valueOf(intArrayList.get(0));
    int oldPos = Integer.valueOf(currentPos);
    int newPos = oldPos-1;

    //Swap position @ move up list
    collections.swap(newList, oldPos, newPos);

    //store ArrayList data into arrays
    myDataFiles = newList.toArray(myDataFiles);

    intArrayList.clear();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This will make our selected item move up, **but** it won't save the state. Meaning the item's position displayed on `ListView` will go back to the way it was upon closing the app